# What if you consume haram without knowing

Tags: halal-haram

I think I have consumed haram [jelly](http://www.lucozadesport.com/product/lucozade-sport-elite/jelly-beans/lucozade-sport-elite-jelly-beans-24-pack/60/) and I am worried of what did I do, not sure if it's halal or haram. What if someone consume and didn't know. How do we know if something is halal without a tag on it?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know what is and is not haram you either need to learn how to read ingredients and judge yourself or you may be better off not eating foods unless they have a tag on them.  Some candies contain gelatin or other things but some don't so it is hard to know if it is haram unless we see the ingredients.

If you want to know if any certain ingredient is haram you can also ask that on this site too :)

If you ate haram jelly without knowing that it was haram then you just need to repent and don't eat it again, because the Qur'an says "Your Lord has decreed upon Himself mercy: that any of you who does wrong out of ignorance and then repents after that and corrects himself - indeed, He is Forgiving and Merciful"